# Set up cookies from one domain to another domain

Tags: php, server, salesforce, cross-domain, setcookie

There are multiple questions and answers regarding set up of cookies of one domain from another domain. I know it is not secure to implement. I have gone through multiple SO questions but do not find any concrete solution.

I would like to know what is secure and possible way to implement it from code side as well as from server side. By refer term server side, it means, If some server rules should define at server like, user agent of domain can accept specific cookies from specific domain and if we can set up such rule to add cookies from another domain, how can we do it in AWS?

I am using AWS hosting for one of my PHP website and another website is in Salesforce, and for that I have to share cookies between each other. Below is PHP code and it is working properly in my localhost, but it does not working on live website.

```
setcookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', time() + 3600,'/','abc.com');
```

I am glad if someone share me tutorial or documentation, if any server rules exist to allow assignment of cookies between cross domain.

Thank you.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the code on the second domain uses AJAX to call a server script in the first domain. This AJAX request can return the cookie values.

Comment: `I have to share cookies between each other`...why do you need to share cookies in the first place? I would probably be addressing that issue rather than looking for workarounds. It's almost certainly not the optimal solution to whatever business problem you're attempting to resolve.

Comment: Barmar: I am already using PHP cURL, and in response I am receiving cookies of remote domain, but how to assign response cookie to that domain?

Comment: ADyson: I have to share cookies because my both websites having common users, to avoid redundancy of multiple login in each domain, I am trying to implement log in at one domain and then share cookies so another domain, so it does not require login to access at same time.